# How to make my wifi network re-connect after it loses connection?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I have setup my wireless network like this:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.70
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.71
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="home-network"
        psk="mypassword"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}

network={
        ssid="work-network"
        psk="mypassword"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

If the wireless connection is broken somehow or the AP is disconnected, I cannot even ping the machine (which I am referring to). If I unplug the usb Wifi and reconnect it, it suddenly re-connects in a second!

Why is this happening? Have I done something wrong in my setup ?